# Updating a For Each Loop in Python

Tags: python, gis, arcgis

The below python code takes a list of files and zips them up.  The only File Geodatabase (File based database) that I need to have is called "Data" so how can I modify the loop to only include the File based database called Data?  To be more specific a File Geodatabase is stored as a system folder that contains binary files that store and manage spatial data.  So I need the entire system folder called Data.gdb.

Many Thanks

```
#**********************************************************************
# Description:
#    Zips the contents of a folder, file geodatabase or ArcInfo workspace
#    containing coverages into a zip file.
# Parameters:
#   0 - Input workspace
#   1 - Output zip file. It is assumed that the caller (such as the
#       script tool) added the .zip extension.
#
#**********************************************************************

# Import modules and create the geoprocessor
import sys, zipfile, arcgisscripting, os, traceback
gp = arcgisscripting.create()

# Function for zipping files 
def zipws(path, zip):
    isdir = os.path.isdir

    # Check the contents of the workspace, if it the current
    # item is a directory, gets its contents and write them to
    # the zip file, otherwise write the current file item to the
    # zip file
    #
    for each in os.listdir(path):
        fullname = path + "/" + each
        if not isdir(fullname):
            # If the workspace is a file geodatabase, avoid writing out lock
            # files as they are unnecessary
            #
            if not each.endswith('.lock'):
                # gp.AddMessage("Adding " + each + " ...")
                # Write out the file and give it a relative archive path
                #
                try: zip.write(fullname, each)
                except IOError: None # Ignore any errors in writing file
        else:
            # Branch for sub-directories
            #
            for eachfile in os.listdir(fullname):
                if not isdir(eachfile):
                    if not each.endswith('.lock'):
                        # gp.AddMessage("Adding " + eachfile + " ...")
                        # Write out the file and give it a relative archive path
                        #
                        try: zip.write(fullname + "/" + eachfile, \
                                       os.path.basename(fullname) + "/" + eachfile)
                        except IOError: None # Ignore any errors in writing file


if __name__ == '__main__':
    try:
        # Get the tool parameter values
        #
        inworkspace = sys.argv[1]
        outfile = sys.argv[2]     

        # Create the zip file for writing compressed data
        #
        zip = zipfile.ZipFile(outfile, 'w', zipfile.ZIP_DEFLATED)
        zipws(inworkspace, zip)
        zip.close()

        # Set the output derived parameter value for models
        #
        gp.setparameterastext(1, outfile)
        gp.AddMessage("Zip file created successfully")

    except:
        # Return any python specific errors as well as any errors from the geoprocessor
        #
        tb = sys.exc_info()[2]
        tbinfo = traceback.format_tb(tb)[0]
        pymsg = "PYTHON ERRORS:\nTraceback Info:\n" + tbinfo + "\nError Info:\n    " + \
                str(sys.exc_type)+ ": " + str(sys.exc_value) + "\n"
        gp.AddError(pymsg)

        msgs = "GP ERRORS:\n" + gp.GetMessages(2) + "\n"
        gp.AddError(msgs)
```

Comment: No, Data.gdb is the name of the File based database and that is the only file I want zipped up.  All other files I do not want included in the zip file.

Comment: If 'Data.gdb' is a directory, then that should be the command line argument to this program and you're done.  No programming required.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way to walk over a directory tree is [os.walk](http://docs.python.org/library/os.html#os.walk) -- does the file/dir separation for you, and also does the recursion down to subdirectories for you.

So:

```
def zipws(path, zip, filename='Data.gdb'):
  for root, dirs, files in os.walk(path):
    if filename in files:
      zip.write(os.path.join(root, filename),
                os.path.join(os.path.basename(root), filename))
      return
```

I'm not certain I've captured the entire logic with which you want to determine the two arguments to `zip.write` (it's not obvious to me from your code), but, if not, that should be easy to adjust.

Also, I'm not sure if you want that `return` at the end: the effect is zipping only **one** file named that way, as opposed to zipping **all** files named that way that may occur in the tree (in their respective subdirectories).  If you know there's only one such file, may as well leave the `return` in (it will just speed things up a bit).  If you want all such files when there's more than one, remove the `return`.

**Edit**: turns out that the "one thing" the OP wants is a **directory**, not a file.  In that case, I would suggest, as the simplest solution:

```
def zipws(path, zip, dirname='Data.gdb'):
  for root, dirs, files in os.walk(path):
    if os.path.basename(root) != dirname: continue
    for filename in files:
      zip.write(os.path.join(root, filename),
                os.path.join(dirname, filename))
    return
```

again with a similar guess wrt the total mystery of what exactly it **is** that you want to use for your archive-name.

Comment: Hi Alex-  I updated my question above so as to provide more detail on Data.gdb (it is a system folder with multiple binary files).  Also I commented out my entire zipws function and added your code and also updated zipws(inworkspace, zip) to be zipws(inworkspace, zip, filename) but when I ran it I get a syntax error.  Thoughts?

Comment: @Josh, re the latter, I just typoed away a closed-paren -- editing to fix.  If the one thing you're looking for is a directory, not a file, simplest IMHO is to look for the basename of root -- since I'm editing anyway I'll show the new version.

Answer (score 0):

Start at this line:

```
    zipws(inworkspace, zip)
```

You don't want to use this this function to build the zip file from multiple files.
It appears you want to build a zip file with just one member.

Replace it with this.

```
     try: 
         zip.write(os.path.join('.', 'Data.gdb'))
     except IOError: 
         pass # Ignore any errors in writing file
```

Throw away the `zipws` function which you -- apparently -- don't want to use.

Read this, it may help: http://docs.python.org/library/zipfile.html

Comment: the Data.gdb is multiple files as it is a File based database.  So will that be an issue?

Comment: @Josh: You should **update** your question to be very specific on this point.  It's not clear what this name means.  Is it a "directory"?  Or is it a "file"?  Please actually update your question to provide the missing information.